# Computing by hand vs. R's magic wand

Tags: r, confidence-interval, computational-statistics

I have fitted a polynomial to a data set that I have. Thus I have obtained coefficients $\beta_i$ for $i=0,1,2$ and have a relationship of the form is $$Y=\beta_0+\beta_{1}X+\beta_{2}X^{2}+\varepsilon$$ between the predictor $X$ and the response $Y$, where $\varepsilon$ is the error term.

My question is about computing **confidence intervals**.
I can compute for each of the coefficients $\beta_i$ the confidence interval using the `confint()`function from R. This gets me three (95%) confidence intervals $[a_0,b_0]$,$[a_1,b_1]$ and $[a_2,b_2]$ for $\beta_0$,$\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

Lets say I would like to predict the *average* value that I will obtain for $Y$ for a new sample point $x=0.25$, that is, I would like to know the confidence interval around this point.
Using the previously obtained confidence intervals for coefficients, I can compute that $x$ has to lie in (with probability 95%) in the interval $$[a_0+a_{1}0.25+a_{2}0.25^{2},b_0+b_{1}\tilde 0.25+b_{2}0.25^{2}].$$

**Unfortunately, when I compare the values that I obtain in this way with the output of the R command `predict(my_fitted_data, data.frame(x=0.25),interval = 'confidence')`, that interval is way smaller than the one I obtaind by computing the interval, as described, by hand.

Did I do anything wrong? If so, what?**

Thank you.

Comment: The parameter estimates are correlated. ``vcov(my_fitted_data)`` shows you the variance-covariance matrix of the parameter estimates, ``cov2cor(vcov(my_fitted_data))`` the correlation matrix. Your approach ignores this correlation.

Comment: @Wolfgang I don't really understand what that means (how to interpret the output of these commands), unfortunately....Is the take-home message: Use the R function for the correct confidence interval?

Comment: @user10324 I asked a similar question a while ago. The answer there should give you what you need. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10439/confidence-interval-for-difference-of-means-in-regression

Comment: Adding to other comments, you are [misunderstanding confidence intervals](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the), moreover, you seem to be asking about *prediction intervals*.

Comment: @mark999 that answer is unfortunately way too much over the top of my head... so it seems that I should just use the `R` command, as stated?

Comment: @Tim No, that I way I emphasized the word "average". For a single point estimate indeed I would be interested in the prediction interval.

Comment: @user10324 yes, your computation by-hand is incorrect and if you want to get proper intervals then better stick to the standard R functions.

Comment: @Tim thanks! ok, that is essentially what I wanted to know (as the details, as the linked answer shows, are too difficult for me to really understand without putting in  a lot of work)

Comment: @Tim I don't think the question is asking about prediction intervals.

Comment: @user10324 still CI's do not give you "95% probability that x has to lie in the interval".

Comment: @mark999 maybe not, it is not clear for me from the question.

Comment: @Tim indeed, they give the interval where with 95% probability that x has to lie *on average* (i.e. sample a lot of x's, take the mean (so that the error term doesn't bear weight any more) and that lies in the CI)

Comment: @user10324 I'll give you an example.

Comment: @user10324 that's a different question to the one you posted. Don't ask entirely new questions in comments, post new questions (after searching as they're likely to be answered in some form already) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mistake you made was to ignore the covariances between the estimators $\hat{\beta}_0$, $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$.

You want a 95% confidence interval for
$$
E(Y|X=0.25) = \beta_0 + 0.25\beta_1 + 0.25^2\beta_2 = a\beta,
$$
with $a = [1\ \ 0.25\ \ 0.25^2]$ and $\beta = [\beta_0\ \ \beta_1\ \ \beta_2]^T$.

Under the usual assumptions (normally distributed errors, etc.), the confidence interval you want is
$$
a\hat{\beta} \pm t_{n-p,\, 0.975}
\sqrt{a\hat{\sigma}^2 (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}a^T},
$$
with $n$ being the sample size, $p$ being the number of regression coefficients including the intercept (i.e. $p=3$), and $t_{n-p,\, 0.975}$ being the value such that $P(T_{n-p} \leq t_{n-p,\, 0.975}) = 0.975$ if $T_{n-p}$ is a Student t random variable with $n-p$ degrees of freedom. We use 0.975 because that gives 0.025 in the upper tail and 0.025 in the lower tail. The matrix $\hat{\sigma}^2 (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$ is the estimated covariance matrix of the estimators $\hat{\beta}$, which can be obtained in R using the `vcov` function ($\mathbf{X}$ is the design matrix).

I acknowledge NRH, who showed me this when I asked a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10439/confidence-interval-for-difference-of-means-in-regression) (the notation I've used here is slightly different).

An example:

```
set.seed(1)

d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))

lm1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data=d)

x.value <- 0.25
conf.level <- 0.95

predict(lm1, data.frame(x = x.value), interval="confidence", level = conf.level)

##         fit        lwr       upr
## 1 0.1254577 -0.2068385 0.4577539

a <- c(1, x.value, x.value^2)

# percentile of the t-distribution to use (0.975 if conf.level is 0.95)
perc <- 1 - (1 - conf.level)/2

# degrees of freedom = sample size - number of coefs
DF <- nrow(d) - length(coef(lm1))

# Confidence interval
(a %*% coef(lm1)) + c(-1, 1)*qt(perc, DF)*sqrt(a %*% vcov(lm1) %*% a)

## [1] -0.2068385  0.4577539
```

Comment: +1 especially the R example clarified it for me. thanks a lot!!

Comment: @user10324 You're welcome.